# UITabBarController preload all ViewControllers when app starts

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar, ios14

It is possible to preload the ViewControllers from a TabBar when the app starts?
The TabBarViewController and 3 ViewControllers created in storyboard.

I have tried this in TabBarViewController

```
self.viewControllers?.forEach({ (vc) in
        vc.loadViewIfNeeded()
})
```

but with no success.

I want all view controllers to load the data and subviews before the user tap on a different tab.

Xcode 12, iOS 14

Comment: In which method of `TabBarViewController` are you calling this? Also, you may want to also call `vc.view.layoutIfNeeded()`, maybe it would be the thing you're looking for.

Comment: @EDUsta I call it in viewDidLoad()

Comment: adding vc.view.layoutIfNeeded() after vc.loadViewIfNeeded() crashes the app with this error: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier button_cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'. all cells are registered and working before.